# Cannot pass context from onpostexecute to sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-context

I have my asyctask class and sharedpreferences class.
in AsyncTask > onpostexecute after successful login i want to set the values to session using sharedpreferences, for that I have to pass context to sharedpreferences class, but in `onpostexecute()` it says context cannot be applied.

**session class**

```
public class Session{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context c;
    private String emailid = "";
    public String getEmailid() {
        emailid=prefs.getString("emailid","");
        return emailid;
    }
    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
        prefs.edit().putString("emailid",emailid).commit();
    }
    public void Session(Context c){
        this.c = c;
        prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("session_data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

**asynctask**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String data = result;
        String success_code = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
            success_code = jObj.getString("resp_code");
            Toast.makeText(c,data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(success_code.equals("1")){
                Toast.makeText(c,"Welcome " + jObj.getString("fullname"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Session obj = new Session();
                obj.setEmailid(jObj.getString("emailid"));

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(c,"Invalid Credentials !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

just look at **Session obj = new Session();** It should be like **Session obj = new Session(c);** but it says cannot be applied here, c is the context which i am passing from mainativity to asynctask.

Comment: cannot do that, this is in asynctask class not in mainactivity.

Answer (score 3):

First thing, you need Static Variable to declare global variable in Class, 
like this:

```
public static Context context;

public Session(Context context){
    this.context= context;
    prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("session_data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> A constructor in Java can not be abstract, final, static and
>   Synchronized.

A constructor initializes an object when it is created. It has the same name as its class and is syntactically similar to a method. However, constructors have no explicit return type.

It should be

```
 public Session(Context c){
        this.c = c;
        prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("session_data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

Comment: this is fine, working, now can you suggest how can i pass some data from onpostexecute to mainactivity ?

Comment: @user3099225 Solved this yet?

Comment: I got some suggestion to use asyncresponse .. not tried yet.